# An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony, doctrine

I made new entities in my project but I have a problem with migrating data to my database.
When I run the command
`bin/console make:migration`

I get

```
In ExceptionConverter.php line 103:                                                                                 
  An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                                                                    

In Exception.php line 28:                                        
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused   

In Driver.php line 28:                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I'm just learning about all of this so I can't figure out what's wrong.
Here is the full code of my .env:

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/webapp-pack ###
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default?auto_setup=0
###< symfony/webapp-pack ###

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=dec360f5f5fb625aa22fd102dc475293
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"

DATABASE_URL="mysql://20_wroblewska:password@127.0.0.1:3306/20_wroblewska?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"

# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=14&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/messenger ###
# Choose one of the transports below
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f/messages
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=redis://localhost:6379/messages
###< symfony/messenger ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
# MAILER_DSN=null://null
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

And my docker-compose.yaml code (this is how it looked untouched, the way it was automatically crated):

```
version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-14}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Which I changed to this, trying to fix it, but honestly I have no idea what I'm doing...

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
        container_name: symfony_mysql
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"   
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 20_wroblewska
            MYSQL_USER: 20_wroblewska
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

Can you please help me, I don't know what to look for and what to change.

Comment: Add to question output of `docker compose ps` command

Comment: once you have containers up, check with a sql client like heidi, host: 127.0.0.1 port:3307 and the remaining info, user,pwd, etc,

Answer (score 1):

have you run docker with the command `docker-compose up -d` ?
Are you sure your .env is correctly configure ? Try replace 3306 by 3307 (port define in docker).

I hope this helps, if not I'm really sorry.